# Can you create multiple JVMs in JNI in a single process?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a C++ framework that runs in a single process and allows for modules, and one type of module I would like to add is a module that loads a JAR and then calls a specific predefined function in it. There can be as many modules running simultaneously as the user desires, which raises the question:

Could each module create a separate JVM with JNI_CreateJavaVM() and those JVMs would be entirely independent of each other (however in the same process)? Or is Java internally relying on globals etc that would make them interfere with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only allowed to create a single VM in each process, and get a single `JNIEnv`. Creation of multiple VMs was once supported in some very old JVM implementations, but no longer is.

See **JNI_CreateJavaVM** in Oracle's [Java 7 JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html):

> As of JDK/JRE 1.2 , creation of multiple VMs in a single process is not supported.

And [IBM's JDK 7 JNI documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaha/invofunc.htm):

> Java on IBM i supports creating only one Java virtual machine (JVM) within a single job or process.

*(presumabely, same limitation applies for IBM AIX JVMs)*

And in more detail [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaha/multjvm.htm):

> You cannot successfully call JNI_CreateJavaVM() more than once in a job, and JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs() cannot return more than one JVM in a list of results.
>
> Support for creating only a single JVM within a single job or process follows the standards of the Oracle America, Inc. reference implementation of Java.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info. This saves me a lot of trouble of going down the wrong path.